# Proof " A la Grothendieck"

Tags: lo.logic, ag.algebraic-geometry

Grothendieck's proof of the well-known Ax–Grothendieck Theorem uses the elegant argument that the existence of a counterexample for the field $\mathbb C$ imply the existence of a counterexample for a finite field. Roughly speaking, we transfer the problem from $\mathbb C$ to finite fields.

recently, Will Sawin, here in mathoverflow, proved that the ring of Hamilton quaternions over $\mathbb H_{2^s}$ is reversible proving that the existence of a counterexample fore some $s$ imply the existence of a counterexample for $s=1$ or $s=2$, (a finite problem  tha is solved with a computer).

There are other examples of this type of proof?

Comment: Too vague and thus too broad. Vote to close. (BTW, please use CW mode when asking for a list of answers; there is a box to tick, you can still do this by editing the question.)

Comment: Maybe you can look at here: http://www.college-de-france.fr/media/historique/UPL51364_Serre_Conf._Luminy_.pdf